# django - Server error loading static files

Tags: django, static, django-staticfiles

So im building my own django site. Right now im stuck with loading the statics.
im getting the following error in the console:

```
 GET http://localhost:8000/static/css/style.css 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Im trying to load a css file using the static taggs:

```
{{ STATIC_URL }}
```

in my settings i've edited the following:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.environ.get('STATIC_ROOT',os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,"static",))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static",),
)
```

also added the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.core.context_processors.static',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

added the following to urls.py so i can navigate to localhost:8000/static/

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
'django.views.static.serve',
{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

I'm not sute what im doing wrong. The PROJECT_ROOT is directing to the root of the project. I'm also using that for my TEMPLATE_DIR, and that works fine.

Hopefully someone can enlighten me! I've been googling around, and looked at other questions, but as far as i can see, i did everything how i'm supposed to!

Thx in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps this can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799835/django-static-files-results-in-404/14800489#14800489

Comment: What is the error? Post the traceback. And what version of Django are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Change the your debug into DEBUG=False
```

Comment: Could you explain why i should change it to this? I've tried it out, still getting the error.

Comment: @KevinvanHengst Wait is your DEBUG = True?

Comment: Change that to DEBUG=False

Comment: Ok, when i changed it to False it works! But what does picking up the css file have to do with the DEBUB being True/False?

Comment: When you set the debug into True (local). The system will check if you have 404.html. If it did not exist you will get 500 error

Comment: The problem was not the DEBUG. I went to the terminal and came across this: `"ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting"` So i cleared my STATIC_ROOT and it works fine now. with DEBUG = True/False

Answer (score 1):

You have STATIC_ROOT in STATICFILES_DIRS ! That's incorrect.

Not sure if your issue is related to that, but it definitively show a lack of understanding of django staticfiles management.

Maybe after reading [this article](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/30382323418/surviving-django-contrib-staticfiles-or-how-to-manage) you'll understand it fully and be able to set it up right.

And you don't need this with DEBUG=True:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
'django.views.static.serve',
{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had the same problem, and then I saw this error message:

> "Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; "
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Your STATICFILES_DIRS
>   setting is not a tuple or list; perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?"

So, I converted the result of

```
(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
```

To a list:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))]
```

Hope this help somebody.