# Why won't Django load my static CSS files?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm having trouble getting Django to load my CSS for my html template. I'm aware that there are a lot of posts like this, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428146/django-server-error-loading-static-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446325/django-css-is-not-not-working), but I'm not sure what else to do here as I've tried several of these types of these solutions to no avail.

Loading up my website using `python manage.py runserver` returns this log:

```
[31/Jul/2016 01:58:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1703
[31/Jul/2016 01:58:29] "GET /static/css/about.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1766
```

I'm not sure if the 404 on the end of the second line of the log refers to a 404 error or not.

I have tried adding the static files to my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'))
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I have tried modifying my `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/static/"

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
)
```

And I of course used the proper loading methods in the actual template itself:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/about.css' %}">
```

Here's my file structure:

```
Personal_Website
|Personal_Website
||settings.py
||urls.py
||etc...
|static
||css
|||about.css
```

Frankly, I'm not sure what else to do here. I feel like I've tried everything with the settings and still I'm getting that same log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have this to serve static file in project directory...

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
```

`os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` This is pointing to Personal_Website folder where settings all file is there...

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same results. My base path is `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` if you need more info.

Comment: @hasherr this will work surely. I replicated exact same thing in my local and that is working... Can you print the `STATICFILES_DIRS` where it pointing to...

Comment: I can't seem to find a good way to print out the variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: In settings.py you can `print STATICFILES_DIRS` then see that in console..

Comment: C:\\Users\\eklei\\Google Drive\\Development\\Personal_Website\\static

Comment: Don't know about windows... But Is that right path to your static folder ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118726/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-hasherr).

Comment: Yes, it is. Is that what it's supposed to do?