# Static files are not loaded in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to follow these [instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) to enable static files in my Django project.
I have

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

in my settings.py file. I have `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` added to the `INSTALLED_APPS = (...)` part
I created a folder `mysite/static/mysite` and put my files there. But after I run the server, I cannot access my files at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/mysite/style.css`.
What I have done wrong?

Comment: What is `STATIC_ROOT` ??

Comment: could you put the code the STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: Perhaps this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799835/django-static-files-results-in-404/14800489#14800489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `settings.py` include this:

```
import os
settings_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(settings_dir))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/mysite/'),
)
```

And in your `urls.py` include these lines at the end:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: 500 error is an internal server error. That's an exception. Can you post the exception's message?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a couple things to check:

- In my projects at least, the static folder is in the app directory, not the project directory. For example, `mysite/myapp/static/myapp/img.jpg` rather than `mysite/static/mysite/img.jpg`. Your project might not be looking in the right place.
- Make sure that {% load staticfiles %} is in your html template before linking the files.
- When you link a file in your html template, rather than direct urls like

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="myapp/css/custom.css">`

use

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myapp/css/custom.css' %}">`

This was enough to get static files working in my projects, without having to modify urls.py or manually set PROJECT_ROOT or STATICFILES_DIRS.

Comment: I do not use constructions like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myapp/css/custom.css' %}">` , I simply try to access static files directly by .../static/style.css and this fails...

Comment: As the documentation you linked says, the template tag is preferable. It looks like both should work though, so the problem is likely that the files are not where the project can access them. If you put the static folder inside an app directory as I described above, it should find them automatically. But if you put them in the main project directory as you have described, you will have to add that to STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py. Look just below point number 4 in the documentation you linked and it explains how to do this.