# Django 1.4 serving media files works, but not static

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, http-status-code-404, django-staticfiles

I am using Django 1.4 and for some reason i am able to serve media files, but not the static ones...
Here is my code:
settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

urls.py:

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
                    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

base.html:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

i get a 404 http not found... what am i doing wrong? An i did create the static folder in my project right next to media

> http://mysite.com:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your INSTALLED_APPS and is this a development site with DEBUG=True?

Comment: yes to both questions... by the way in production should i put DEBUG to false??

Comment: Would this be of any help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799835/django-static-files-results-in-404/14800489#14800489

Comment: tried it with no luck

Comment: ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is deprecated in Django 1.4. Also instead os STATIC_URL is recommended to use {% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static folder should be under one app that you use it for.

For example, I have a project named `my_project` and an application named `my_app`, I have some static files used in `my_app` so I put them under `~/project_path/my_project/my_app/static`

**NB:** `my_app` must be in `INSTALLED_APPS`. See `STATICFILES_FINDERS` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS).

**Edit:**

As a best practice, you should have a global static folder in one app (the main one), for example a static folder how contains your html template basic resources as jquery, bootstrap, your global style.

And for the static files how's required only for one app, for example app `foo`, these files should be under `foo/static` folder

Comment: what if i need the same static file for 2 or more apps?? i duplicate the file or collect-static automatically detects and only uses 1?

Comment: yeah it use only one file, like @Andrew S say, we have used collectstatic to test if Django find or not the static folder, but it's used only for production(for example for apache). If in the future you would to delete one apps, it can't infect your others apps because any apps is static folder is independant from each other, that's the trick !

Answer (score 1):

I suggest removing the explicit media and static views and allowing the staticfiles app to create them (when DEBUG is True under development).

Check the default finders are present in your settings.py
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS

Either add your project static directory to STATICFILES_DIRS (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) or place app specific static folders under each app. The app needs to be listed in the INSTALLED_APPS for the finders to locate the static content.

Do not place static files into STATIC_ROOT yourself. This directory is managed by the **collectstatic** command. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#deployment

Comment: default finders are present. i tried adding os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), to STATICFILES_DIRS with no luck.. is that what you are suggesting? i want to keep my static files in one place only like the projects directory not inside the apps because i have some common resources

Comment: im not sure i understood.. i don't have a view for /static.. only the routing in urls and the rest in my settings.py

Comment: Remove the static entry from urls.py.  Also, 'STATIC_ROOT' should not be where your project static files are kept. The 'STATIC_ROOT' directory is where the 'collectstatic' command will place all static content for serving in production.

Comment: i did that and it only creates the admin static files.. it seems like it does not recognize my other static files for some reason

Comment: What is the full path to the root of the project's static files? That is the path you add to STATICFILES_DIRS. It should **not** be the same as STATIC_ROOT. As this is a directory outside of an app you don't need to add it to INSTALLED_APPS. Running collectstatic will copy all known static content to the STATIC_ROOT so it's a good test to see what is being found as static content. During development you don't serve files from the STATIC_ROOT and should use the staticfiles app to serve them automatically. There's no need to add the static URL to urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i define my media url in settings.py:

```
import os
ABSOLUTE_PATH           = os.path.dirname(__file__)
MEDIA_ROOT              = os.path.join(ABSOLUTE_PATH, '../media')
MEDIA_URL               = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT             = os.path.join(ABSOLUTE_PATH, '../static')
STATIC_URL              = "/static/"
```

So like you see the difference is ../media and ../static

Is mysite in your installed apps ? Django look inside your installed apps and check if there's a static folder there.

Comment: Where is the location of your static folder ?

Comment: /home/username/git/mysite/mysite/static

Comment: Is your settings.py here /home/username/git/mysite/mysite/settings.py ? and /home/username/git/mysite your project folder ?

Comment: Another think, verify that you have this in your settings file:
`STATICFILES_FINDERS     = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    )`

Comment: its here /home/username/git/mysite/mysite/settings.py

Comment: and yes i have the staticfiles_finder like that

Comment: Run this command `./manage.py collectstatic` and check if your files are copied here /home/username/git/mysite/static/

Comment: only the admin static files were copied to /home/username/git/mysite/mysite/static/

Comment: So Django doesn't know that you have a static files there.
Is mysite in your installed apps ?

Comment: No its not, only the apps.. but i tried adding now and it gives Error: No module named mysite

Comment: It's the error, Django look inside your installed apps and check if there's a static folder there. So could you post your settings.py and check if you have a `__init__.py` file inside  /home/username/git/mysite/mysite

Comment: yes i have __init__.py there.. i could put my static files under my apps, but at this point i have them all together in one folder and its being shared accross multiple apps