# Static file access

Tags: django

I am trying to use a static file in Django. I have set it us a below, but it doesn't find the file. This is on localhost.

In urls:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

In settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT  = "C:/path/to/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (....'django.contrib.staticfiles', ...)
```

Copy-pasting the static root into explorer does go to the folder with the json2_min.js file

HTML:

```
<script src="/static/json2_min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Access the static files like this in your template `{{ STATIC_URL }}json2_min.js`. Also have you put `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your installed apps? Did you read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: I do have django.contrib.staticfiles in my installed apps. {{ STATIC_URL }} just reads the static_url, which is "/static/", like I wrote in the script src. I did read the docs. That's how I started.

Comment: You don't need the `urls.py` configuration. If you follow the tutorial or this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799835/django-static-files-results-in-404/14800489#14800489

Comment: Still no dice. Removed the url configuration and moved the static_root path to staticfiles_dirs. The staticfiles_finders were already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found two ways to solve this.

One, I REMOVED 'django.contrib.staticfiles' from INSTALLED_APPS.

or, two, I changed the word static:

in urls,

```
 url(r'^not_static/(?P<path>.*)$'.....
```

and correspondingly in the html:

```
<script src="/not_static/json2_min.js"></script>
```

I must have been trying to override some native static functionality.  Seems there should be a third solution that actually makes the default static functionality work, but I din't find it.

Comment: Good that it worked for you, but that's really not the main issue, you've mustve missed something critically because the way you're doing it now, isn't how it should work.

Comment: Yes, the elusive third solution.