# django using images in css

Tags: css, django

okay so I didn't make any changes to my settings.py, the image I want to use in my css is here.

```
C:\djcode\testapp1\testing1\testingapp1\static\testingapp1\images
```

my style.css file is in here.

```
C:\djcode\testapp1\testing1\testingapp1\static\testingapp1
```

my manage.py file is in here.

```
C:\djcode\testapp1\testing1
```

and my settings.py file is in here.

```
C:\djcode\testapp1\testing1\testing1
```

My templates (including index.html) are here.

```
C:\djcode\testapp1\testing1\testingapp1\templates
```

In my index.html file, I linked the css by typing this on the top of my index.html file.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'testingapp1/style.css' %}" />
```

I tried using the image in my css file by doing this.

```
background: url(images/picture.png);
```

I also tried.

```
background: url({% static 'testingapp1/images/picture.png' %})
```

but that didn't work either. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What's your `STATIC_ROOT` path?

Comment: my static root is just STATIC_ROOT = '', STATIC_URL = '/static/' and no STATICFILES_DIRS... I was afraid that if I added a static_root or static_url that it might mess up my linking to the css in my index.html

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799835/django-static-files-results-in-404/14800489#14800489 - Furthermore I would definately not recommend using Django template tags within your static resources. The reasoning behind that is because you have to serve these via the template pipeline (ie. compile them and serve) or use inline scripts and css. And THAT is really, really bad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `STATIC_ROOT`, and also set your `STATICFILE_DIRS` for local development, otherwise Django won't know where to serve your local static files during development.

`STATIC_ROOT` is where your static media and any 3rd party static media get collected to for deployment. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is the directory or directories `django.contrib.static` will serve files from if `DEBUG` is True.

Hope that gets you going.